# Dividing a polynomial of degree greater than 5

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

$f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree greater than $5$. When $f(x)$ is divided by some polynomial, the quotient is $(x-\gamma)(x-\lambda)(x-\theta)$. Show that the remainder of $f(x)$ when divided by $(x-\gamma)(x-\lambda)(x-\theta)$ can be written as,

$\displaystyle \bigg[\frac{2\eta - \mu\left(\lambda-\theta\right)}{\left(\theta-\lambda\right)}\bigg]x- \bigg(\frac{\eta\lambda-\theta\left[ \mu(\lambda-\theta)-\eta\right]}{(\lambda-\theta)}\bigg)$

---

I tried writing the remainder as $Ax^2+Bx+C$ and trying to find the values of coefficients. As in the given answer $A$ must vanish, but I don't know how it happens. Maybe my method is totally wrong. I have no idea. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: seems like something is missing. Any information about the polynomial with which the $f(x)$ is divided?

Comment: @bigbang No. It just says "some polynomial"

Comment: The other odd thing is that the given expression depends on $\theta, \lambda$ but not on $\gamma$. Something is missing, as said already.

Comment: @dxiv I think $\mu$ and/or $\eta$ contains $\gamma$

Comment: @Teshan Fact remains that the statement of the problem does not hold true as written. Consider for example $f(x)=x^6-x^5+x^2$, the other "*some polynomial*" $=x^3$, and $\gamma=\lambda=0, \theta=1\,$. Then all the constraints are satisfied, but $f(x) = x^2(x-1) \cdot x^3 + x^2$ so the remainder of the division is $x^2\,$.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you! This was really helpful!